# How to make a button with dynamic text using Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

What is the workaround to create 3 buttons with the same design but different texts (short text, medium length text, long text):

a) do I need 3 different images as a background ? What if i don’t know the length of the text ?

b) or I can use a single image and shrink/stretch it horizontally/vertically somehow when a text needs more/less space to fit in?

I hope i don’t need hundreds of images for each button :)

I’m just a beginner. What is the best practice ?

Here is how I create a responsive button and text:

```
buttonSprite2 = game.add.sprite(352, 76,'button');
buttonSprite2.position.set(200, 0);
buttonSprite2.inputEnabled = true;
buttonSprite2.events.onInputDown.add(listener2, this);

var style = { font: "32px Arial", fill: "#ffffff", wordWrap: true, align: "center", backgroundImage:'button'};
buttonText2 = game.add.text(0, 0, "stop text", style);
buttonText2.wordWrapWidth = game.world.width - 400;

// trying to center the text within the button
buttonText2.position.set(buttonSprite2.x + 100, buttonSprite2.y+15);

// trying to make the button responsive 
if(buttonText2.width < game.world.width - 400){
    buttonSprite2.width = buttonText2.width + 200;
}
else{
    buttonSprite2.width = game.world.width - 300;
    buttonSprite2.height = buttonText2.height + 30;
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example of how you're currently adding a button, and are you using Phaser 2 or 3?

Comment: @JamesSkemp sure, I'm using Phaser 2. I've added the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `load`(in `preload` function) image only once. But you need to `add`(in `create` function) 3 images for 3 buttons.

For changing size of this button images according to text size. First you add image then add text. Now, after adding text, check for `height` or `width` of that text object and change size of the button image according to the `height` and `width` of text.

You may define seperate function to do this. So, you can get rid of redundant code if you have too many buttons.

Comment: Is it possible to resize just the middle of the image ? maybe on a lower level like pixi or even webgl ?

Comment: @FredMer don't know much about lower level apis (pixi or webgl). But you can divide image in 3 parts and load them separately. like upper, middle and lower then you can just `scale` the middle part.